# Update multiple rows based on unique values in another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two columns. The table columns are name, and companyID, and they are in the [dbo].[Suppliers] table.

I need to update the CompanyID values ONLY for Unique Names.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Suppliers]
  SET CompanyId = 46
  WHERE Name IN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name
    FROM [dbo].[Suppliers]
  );
```

i.e.

Trying to get this

```
Name CompanyID
A      5
B      5
C      5
A      5
```

To look like:

```
Name CompanyID
A      6
B      6
C      6
A      5
```

Unfortunately, my query above is not doing the trick.

Appreciate any and all help. Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't the second `Name='A'` supposed to change too?  Or, to rephrase that, how are we or the database meant to know which row to update?  For example, are there any other columns?

Comment: How do you determine which company id to update them with? Given I assume you have a lot more rows in your real table. And if you only have 2 columns in your supplier table, how do you order it? You would really benefit from an identity column.

Comment: @MatBailie I think OPs point is they want to set the distinct set of suppliers to one company, the second distinct set to the next company etc.

Comment: @DaleK

That's exactly right Dale. The point is just to set all the unique names to a certain companyID or value. The duplicate companyID's don't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression to add a row number to each name, then update that CTE but specify only the first row for each name...

```
WITH
  uniquely_identified AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY companyID)  AS name_row_id,
    *
  FROM
    [dbo].[Suppliers]
)
UPDATE
  uniquely_identified
SET
  CompanyId = 46
WHERE
  name_row_id = 1
;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b5eba30b3bed71216ec678e9cffa6b9

Comment: This is the answer (when the system allows me to, I will mark it). Thank you all! That was too easy for yall. Hope this helps others who have a similar problem!

A

Comment: @DakeK One more day of 200+ ratings. Only 118 more such days to go!

Comment: @MatBailie I want to, but I'm a noob with only 11 rep, so can't until 15 :(